# Interpolate movement by incremental steps

Tags: animation, interpolation

I have a question for which I can't find an answer: I would like to move an object from one point to another along an axis, and I would like the movement to interpolate by increments (in my case the increment is 2). As an example, let's say that on frame 1, my object has Location X = 0, and on frame 10 it has Location X = 8. I would like it to interpolate its movement like this:

Frame 1 & 2: Location X constant at 0

Frame 3 & 4: Location X constant at 2

Frame 5 & 6: Location X constant at 4

Frame 7 & 8: Location X constant at 6

Frame 9 & 10: Location X constant at 8

That would create an interpolation curve that looks like stairs. Do you know any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select your keyframes in the *Graph Editor* and you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> or use the menu *Key -> Add F-Curve Modifier -> Stepped Interpolation*.

[image]

The options for the modifier are in the N-panel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just tried it, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, I knew it was something that would exist but was unable to google the right words to find it. Have a nice day!

Comment: Want a [free .gif](https://imgur.com/a/i5gO1WY)? ... :D